# Why in NextJS, logo is not visible when visiting from page URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My logo is not loading with /page URL

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7eTe.png)

Here is my **components/LayoutWrapper.js**

```
 import Image from 'next/image'
 import icon from '../assets/images/Icon.svg'

 <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
   <div className="mr-3 pt-2">
     <Image src={icon} width="25px" height="25px" alt="Blog Logo" />
       {typeof siteMetadata.headerTitle === 'string' ? (
         <div className="  "></div>
       ) : (
         siteMetadata.headerTitle
       )}
   </div>
   {typeof siteMetadata.headerTitle === 'string' ? (
     <div className="hidden h-7 text-2xl font-medium sm:block">
       {siteMetadata.headerTitle}
      </div>
    ) : (
      siteMetadata.headerTitle
    )}
  </div>
```

I want to show my logo on the entire page, visiting from any link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in console. Check your [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0oSI.jpg) first, other pages are not impacted.
Error 404 is your only problem